# Junk from vendor libraries flooding log4j

Tags: java, logging, jakarta-ee, log4j

How can I best prevent these libraries from flooding my own apps log4j bus? I do not want to set everything to ERROR, but at this rate the vendor library is flooding up the log file at a rate of about a gig/day. I do not want it to log anything to this file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by [Jon Skeet´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235229/junk-from-vendor-libraries-flooding-log4j/1235247#1235247), you should configure log4j to ignore the classes from the vendor library. Usually there is a file named `log4j.xml` that one can put the package names and the threshold category to print like this:

```
   <category name="httpclient.wire">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.apache.commons.httpclient">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.hibernate">
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>

   <category name="net.sf.jasperreports">
      <priority value="ERROR"/>
   </category>
```

Take a look at [the manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) for details.

Answer (score 7):

Is the vendor using categories reasonably? If so, set *just their root category* to ERROR and leave everything else as normal. That way you should be able to filter out their non-error messages but still see your own info/debug/etc.

That's most of the point of categories :)

Comment: Seriously, I think the answer is just ... use the log4j configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, if all else fails you could extend LogImpl and have it inject a property into all of your logging calls and set a PropertyFilter on all of your appenders. Hope it wouldn't come to that, though.

(mind you, this is coming from log4net - I assume it all works mostly the same, but I'm just shooting from the hip)